# Populating all drop down fields from database look up tables

Tags: java, oracle, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, oracle10g

I have an application which does have around 25 to 25 look up tables.

When I select create new record or modify exiting records, drop down columns are populated from look up tables. Currently I am querying from look up tables separately. It takes almost 6-7 seconds to populate drop down fields when user click new record button or edit button.

What is the best approach in dealing such situations?

How can I make one view to execute one query rather than several queries to populate all drop down fields?

Any insight or help is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things you can do:

1. If lookup tables don't change or don't change often, cache them
2. Delay lookup of the dropdown values and load them after the rest of the page loads in a way which would not be noticable to user
3. It looks like you have too many fields on one page, consider splitting the form in several pages

Comment: Including some lazy loading will also help. maybe you addept this line to your answer. +1 anyway

Comment: These lookup tables do not change that often, but it cannot be hard coded values. Splitting of drop downs is impossible as those have to be in one single page.

Comment: What do you mean by lazy loading?

Answer (score 1):

It takes as long as 6 to 7 seconds? That sounds like you may not be using (JDBC) connection pooling. Are you? If you are not already using it, connection pooling should dramatically speed things up. In connection pooling, you get a connection, use it, and close it as quickly has possible. Doing so, I think you can stick with querying each table separately.